# Highcharts Highmaps How to import data from google spreadsheet

Tags: highcharts

I want to bulid a map like this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/89mza2bg/2/)

but with data from this spreadsheet: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16AL59eH385JODQsnbB9vYeJ0liSYgNbELRdkHhb78vE/edit#gid=2084475733`

To import data from there I added this code:

```
  data: {
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '16AL59eH385JODQsnbB9vYeJ0liSYgNbELRdkHhb78vE',
    seriesMapping: [{
      'hc-key': 0,
      'infiziert': 1,
      'tote': 2,
      'genesen': 3,
      'bundesland': 4
    }]
    ,
    complete: function(options) {
      options.series[0].name = 'Corona';
    }
  },
```

Unfortunately I do not get the result I wanted: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/89mza2bg/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `value` to `seriesMapping`:

```
data: {
  seriesMapping: [{
    hc-key: 0,
    value: 2,
    ...
  }],
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uvczj6ne/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.data

Comment: Thank you, @ppotaczek. Just one little problem following your solution. I changed the position of the datalabels programmatically by an event (render function) and it worked fine as long as the data came from an array: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/89mza2bg/9/) When I import data from google sheet the datalabels do not keep to their positions [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uvczj6ne/)

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, You need to disable animation: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uvczj6ne/1/